# Perl way of using cut,grep,uniq

Tags: perl, split, cut, uniq

I am running a Perl script inside a Perl script, and the output of the script is something like this

```
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/angyvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/aqmmgvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/69aqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/69aavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/qqmavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/wttvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/9aaqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/9aaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/a1vqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/maaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 1qatvqnqth. heqqq 1qatvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng fmtvqnqth. heqqq fmtvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng gcaavqnqth. heqqq gcaavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng gq9vqnqth. heqqq gq9vqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng hvavqnqth. heqqq hvavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng q9vqnqth. heqqq q9vqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 9vaqvqnqth. heqqq 9vaqvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcaavqnqth. heqqq mcaavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcqrvqnqth. heqqq mcqrvqnqth.
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/angyvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/aqmmgvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/69aqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/69aavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/qqmavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/wttvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/9aaqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/9aaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/a1vqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/maaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 1qatvqnqth. heqqq 1qatvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng fmtvqnqth. heqqq fmtvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 6caavqnqth. heqqq 6caavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 6q9tvqnqth. heqqq 6q9tvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng q9vqnqth. heqqq q9vqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 9vaqvqnqth. heqqq 9vaqvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcaavqnqth. heqqq mcaavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcqrvqnqth. heqqq mcqrvqnqth.
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/angyvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/aqmmgvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/69aqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/69aavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/qqmavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/wttvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/9aaqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/9aaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/a1vqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/maaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
```

I need to get an output like this

```
tm9/raaqHRW /111111111/ty9a1
tm9/raawV9h /111111111/ty9a4
tm9/raaaRX6 /111111111/ty9a7
```

I am currently writing the output of the script to a file and doing as follows,

```
grep "cmt /tm9" output_file | cut -d'/' -f2,3,9,10 | cut -d '.' -f1 | uniq
```

Is there a Perl way to do this?

Comment: [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), [`perldoc -f grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html). Alternatively, hire a programmer. (This question does not show any research effort.)

Comment: As I said in my comment above, "This question does not show any research effort". You're essentially asking us to write code for you. You haven't even attempted to do it yourself. This is not a programming question, this is "do my job for me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will teach you how to fish:

- `-n` to read in a file line by line
- `-a` to split each line into `@F` (and emulate `cut`)
- list slices to access items stored in `@F` to emulate `cut`'s `-f` flag
- regex conditional to emulate `grep`
- use hash keys to emulate `uniq`