# Using cut,grep,uniq in perl way

Tags: arrays, perl, split, grep

I am running a Perl script inside a Perl script, and the output of the script is something like this. These values are stored in an array

```
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/angyvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/aqmmgvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/69aqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/69aavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/qqmavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/wttvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/9aaqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/9aaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/a1vqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaqHRW /myqq1fqq1er/maaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a1.1.e.1234567891008547.ahqva
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 1qatvqnqth. heqqq 1qatvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng fmtvqnqth. heqqq fmtvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng gcaavqnqth. heqqq gcaavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng gq9vqnqth. heqqq gq9vqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng hvavqnqth. heqqq hvavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng q9vqnqth. heqqq q9vqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 9vaqvqnqth. heqqq 9vaqvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcaavqnqth. heqqq mcaavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcqrvqnqth. heqqq mcqrvqnqth.
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/angyvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/aqmmgvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/69aqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/69aavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/qqmavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/wttvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/9aaqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/9aaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/a1vqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raawV9h /myqq1fqq1er/maaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a4.1.e.1234567891014523.ahqva
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 1qatvqnqth. heqqq 1qatvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng fmtvqnqth. heqqq fmtvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 6caavqnqth. heqqq 6caavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 6q9tvqnqth. heqqq 6q9tvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng q9vqnqth. heqqq q9vqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng 9vaqvqnqth. heqqq 9vaqvqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcaavqnqth. heqqq mcaavqnqth.
[qNFq] cqqq aarvqca qntereatqng mcqrvqnqth. heqqq mcqrvqnqth.
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/angyvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/aqmmgvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/69aqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/69aavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/qqmavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/wttvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/9aaqvqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/9aaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/a1vqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
# aAM axac: cmt /tm9/raaaRX6 /myqq1fqq1er/maaavqnqth/rmn/cqqqa/newfqq1er/111111111/ty9a7.1.e.1234567891020719.ahqva
```

I need to get an output like this

```
tm9/raaqHRW /111111111/ty9a1
tm9/raawV9h /111111111/ty9a4
tm9/raaaRX6 /111111111/ty9a7
```

I am currently writing the output of the script to a file and doing as follows,

```
grep "cmt /tm9" output_file | cut -d'/' -f2,3,9,10 | cut -d '.' -f1 | uniq
```

Is there a Perl way to do this?

Comment: Of course there is. What problem are you having?

Comment: I used grep and was able to retain the data structure as array. that is, I grep with characters starting with # and stored the result in an array. I am new to perl and I did not know how to do it keeping it as an array. I only knew to break them and process

Comment: If your [question gets closed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42051608/176646), don't re-post the exact same question again. Read the guidance in the close reason, clarify your question based on other people's comments, and try to improve your question so that it can be reopened.

Comment: This question is an identical copy of your preceding question [*Perl way of using cut,grep,uniq*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051608/perl-way-of-using-cut-grep-uniq) which was closed because it was "too broad". Why do you think this should be treated differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F/ -nle '/cmt \/tm9/ && do { $_ = join "/", @F[1,2,8,9]; s/\..*//; print if ++$h{$_} == 1}' output_file
```

Are you looking for this answer?

Comment: But I am having the values in array and not in file

Comment: You could get a better answer when you were more precise in describing your task. My perl one-liner does exactly what your piped commands combination does.

Comment: "I am currently writing the output of the script to a file and doing as follows," this is what I have said. But what I need is  "I am running a Perl script inside a Perl script, and the output of the script is something like this. These values are stored in an array"........ So can you please have a look and tell me. I am new to perl

Comment: Show your perl script.

Comment: No I can't.. Its confidential